# Read full Json file in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a json file with 1546 distinct items. Somewhere in the process of extracting the item id's I'm left with only 20 id's.

Here is my code.

```
with open('data.json') as access_json:
    data = json.load(access_json)

def get_item_ids():
    all_items = data['items']
    for item_data in all_items:
        item_id = item_data['item_id']
    save_data.append(item_id)

save_data = []

get_item_ids()

with open('item_ids_test.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(save_data, file)
```

The file I'm writing only contains 20 id's, although there are 1546 in the original json file. What am I missing? I think it must happen when I read the file into a dictionary, the 'data' object is relatively short.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seeing the JSON would be helpful.

Comment: So, `save_data` is length 20? It means there are only 20 things in that list. If you have more ids than that, this data structure is nested differently than just having everything right under "items". No way we can figure this out without the data. But its a pretty big example, so maybe you can dig through the original json first.

Comment: Hi Erika! Welcome to StackOverflow. Seeing as the question is related to this specific JSON file, sharing the JSON file would be great! See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're overwriting the `item_id` variable each time through the `for` loop. So you're only appending the last one to `save_data`. Move `save_data.append(item_id)` into the loop.

Comment: I don't see how you're even getting 20 id's, you should only get one.

Comment: your loop keeps the *last id* out of all of them in the original file. Note sure what you expected that to do. There should only be *one* item. there isn't 20

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments, I really appreciate the feedback. I was messing around with the JSON file and when formatted it only has 12105 lines, and the first item consists of 623, which gives you about 20 items for the whole file. So, I think that means my code is actually right and the problem is that I'm not downloading the full file from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Indent  the line of `save_data.append(item_id)` to:

```
with open('data.json') as access_json:
    data = json.load(access_json)

def get_item_ids():
    all_items = data['items']
    for item_data in all_items:
        item_id = item_data['item_id']
        save_data.append(item_id)

save_data = []

get_item_ids()

with open('item_ids_test.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(save_data, file)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually how I had it originally, I messed up the formatting when I transferred it over.